Is it possible to run RPC commands without installing the entire Bitcoind
I am interested to run bitcoin mining https://github.com/jgarzik/pyminer/blob/master/pyminer.py , I understand that it inherently calls bitcoind to run some RPC commands to broadcast once a nonce is achieved etc... Is it possible to run RPC commands without installing the entire blockchain

Does this answer your question? Do I need to download the entire blockchain in order to use bitcoin-cli?
